# Finding external IP of Windows machine

Tags: networking, tcp, remote-access, static-ip-address, ipconfig

I'm trying to access my Windows PC filesystem externally.

I asked my ISP to give me a static IP.

I also assigned an internal static IP to that machine inside the settings of my router (which works).

If I navigate to : https://www.whatismyip.com/ I see an address which belongs to my router (I also see the same address in the homepage of my router).

My configuration is:

I have an 'Asus AC-RT 5300' router connected to my 'Fiber to RJ45' adapter.
I also have a 'TP-Link DECO M4' connected to my router as an access point, and the Windows PC is connected via RJ45 cable to the 'DECO'

My question is: How do I find the specific external IP of the Windows PC so I could access its filesystem from outside my network?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would have been that your entire network would have had the same IP address. So all the devices on your network would have the same external IP address and NAT internally would help route the traffic

Comment: Thanks for your reply! To my understanding NAT does the work automatically (or am I wrong?) Can I access the NAT table and see the exact route of the machine I'm trying to access? And also - assuming I have that route - I just use that instead of the external ip when trying to connect remotely?

Comment: @Idanis I am not so sure sorry. I am not an networking expert but maybe someone here can answer